# Correct way to interrupt a callback

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, multithreading, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will present my problem with an example. I have a callback of Imu messages which I want to integrate on the fly. In a parallel thread I want to access the integrated value from the callback and reset the integration if some condition is met.

Let me present an example.

```
void Camera::imuCb(const sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  if(start_integration_) {
      // integrate IMU
  } else if(reset_integration_) {
    // update integrated values in the following variables
    Rotation_; // this is Eigen::Matrix3d type and is a member of `camera` class which will be accessed in `camera::foo`
    updated_prior_ = true; // set this flag so that we know Rotation matrix is updated in camera::foo
    start_integration_ = true; // for next callback in this function
    // reset integration and start a fresh
  }
}

...

void camera::foo(cv::Mat img)
{
    reset_integration_ = true;
    start_integration_ = false;
    while(ros::ok())
    {
      // wait until Rotation matrix is updated in the imuCb function
      if(prior_updated_) {
        prior_updated_ = false; // ok, now it is updated, exit and process the variable
        break;
      }
    }
   // do some processing using hte updated matrix `Rotation_`
}
```

Note that `camera::foo` is running in the main thread.

The gist is thus:

Whenever `camera::foo` is called I want the integration to stop in the `camera::imuCb` and use the integrated `Rotation_` in the `camera::foo` function.

My doubt is; is what I am doing the right approach? What is the most efficient way to implement this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348470/correct-way-to-interrupt-a-callback/) by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-04-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on 2020-04-05**:
Yes, that's something I am trying with right now. Although I don't think memory race would be an issue here since the next time I am going to update `Rotation_` is in the next call to `camera::foo`.

**Comment by [anonymous25787](https://answers.ros.org/users/25787/anonymous25787/) on 2020-04-05**:
I just wanted to be sure if what I am implementing is in fact the correct approach or if there were other more efficient approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didn't have time to make a better answer, but could you use a conditional (that is set True by foo) before assigning a value to the final variable. The callback wouldn't stop, however, the Rotation_ isn't going be updated and you are able to use the last value. Don't forget the memory race. - I'm not sure with I got the idea.

---

Originally posted by [Teo Cardoso](https://answers.ros.org/users/31965/teo-cardoso/) with karma: 378 on 2020-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0